# How to assign a sequential number (gapless) to a record on INSERT in a transactional sql database?

Tags: sql, database, rdbms

Let's say we have to store orders in the database and the requirement is that the orders should be numbered as `YEAR/NUM` where `NUM` is a number like `1, 2, 3,...` **without any gaps** starting with 1 each year.

How to implement that the right way?

The first thought is:

```
last_num = get_int('select max(num) from orders where year = :current_year:')
next_num = last_num + 1
execute('insert into orders (year, num) values (:current_year:, :next_num:)');
```

That will do it in the most cases for most systems. But if you have very high load there is a possibility of a race condition that 2 threads ask for `last_num` simultaneously and obtain the same number. How to solve that? Do you need to do something with the transaction? Or something with locking a database table?

*The solution should be database vendor independent. Just a theoretical transactional sql database.*

UPDATE 1. Actually you can have a similar situation in a banking database where you have a field with how much money the guy has on his account. Now you need to add some money to his account (last_state + more_money). You can have the same race condition here at reading the `last_state`.

Comment: You mysql's `AUTO_INCREMENT` field modifier.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are actually using.  I'm removing the two databases, so you can add the one appropriate tag.

Comment: Keep the fields separate for the YEAR and the AUTO_INCREMENT.  You can query them or print them out together but best practice is separate.

Comment: @IgorMukin . . . Your update *emphasizes* the point I try to make in my answer:  banks do not identify records by keeping the year with a gapless sequential number.  That is not the best way to identify records in a relational database.  Auto-increment/identity or GUIDs are.

Comment: Using `select max()` will not work in a multi-user environment unless you lock the entire table.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this work for the transaction, but that requires a trigger.  Most databases support the ANSI standard function `ROW_NUMBER()`, which allows you to do this on output:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by year order by id) as year_seqnum
from table t;
```

I would recommend having an `auto_increment`/`identity`/`sequence` id in the table or a creation date to capture the sequential ordering of rows (there can be gaps in such a column).  The database can automatically update this field on input and you can use it to assign the sequence number per year later.

There are important reasons why having the database implement its own sequence number is a much, much better idea than trying to get a sequence number without holes.

Basically, to really do what you want, you have to lock the database for each `insert` transaction in order to get exactly the correct number -- with no gaps or duplicates.  This is called a "serializable transaction".  And, although supported by databases, is a very high bar performance-wise.  In addition, deletions and perhaps updates to transactions become a nightmare.  If you delete the first transaction of the year, you basically have to lock the entire year's worth of data in order to adjust the sequence numbers.  And, there can be no inserts during this time.

Comment: The problem with using a auto_increment/identity/sequence, is that in case of a rollback of the transaction, sequences are not rolled back, so each rollback will cause a gab.

Comment: @MTilsted . . . You are missing the point.  A column of that nature is used to assign *ordering*, not a sequential column with no gaps.  With such a field, you can calculate a sequential column when you need it.

Comment: @GordonLinoff The question is "How to assign the next number to a record on INSERT" and not "How to calculate the numbers afterwards". Imagine that the number is so important that it has to be kept in the database and generated instantly.

Comment: @IgorMukhin . . . Then it is a very expensive operation and the requirement is probably not compatible with other requirements.  Having an auto-incremented/identity column is the best way to uniquely identify rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It is not about uniquely identifying rows. May be reading my "UPDATE 1" will help you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done, but consider if You can delete rows later and do not renumber, You would end up with gapes anyway.

You can make unique constraint on (num, year) and Your first thought would work well if chances of race conditions are low. Every collision would just mean one failed transaction, You can retry automatically.

Answer (score 0):

A theoretical answer to theoretical question.

Gaps in sequence can appears when:

- transaction A begins
- A allocates (reserves) a new number in the sequence (say, 1)
- transaction B begins
- B allocates (reserves) next number in the sequence (say, 2)
- A fails and rolls back
- B commits with sequence value 2

The sequence value 1 is not used in the final committed data - it is a gap

In theory, to prevent these kind of gaps you need to make sure that no two transactions are running in parallel. It is relatively easy to implement this in practice - just lock the whole table for the duration of the transaction and make all concurrent transactions to wait in queue. Or set transaction isolation level to `serializable`.

In practice, it usually reduces the throughput of the system and people don't do it.

---

In your second example of banking database, I would not do it like you described. I store a simple list of all actions (deposits and withdrawals) that happened with the account (just a date and a positive or negative amount of the single transaction). I do not have a permanent field that contains the balance of the account.

When the statement is printed I sum up all actions (over this account) till the needed date to get the balance of the account at a given date.

So, there is no place for race condition at all with this approach.

Comment: Thanks. But in banking your have to have the balance field precalculated at hand, cause... many reasons ))))

Comment: @IgorMukhin, I don't claim that I wrote banking software. In internal database for the company I work at I implemented it as I described. But, that part of the database is small and any approach would work satisfactory. If you have to store such calculated values, one way to guarantee correctness is to serialize transactions (this is a generic, theoretical, vendor independent method) There may be other methods, I don't know.